# Adding TinCan to a Shared project in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, project, shared

I want to use TinCan in my shared project in Xamarin, 
So i can use it for both iOS and Android.
But when I install the tincan package with NuGet, I get:

Could not install package 'TinCan 0.0.5.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v4.4', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Does TinCan support Xamarin?  I don't see anything in the docs to suggest that it does.

Comment: I made a java bindings library and copied all the classes in it, after that i changed some things and generated a dll for my shared project, looks like it's working.